# Php validation on multiple numeric fields for multiple checks

Tags: php, validation, server

I am trying to validate multiple numeric fields for multiple checks ie. There are 6 numeric field and I want to run 6 checks.

1. Firstly, total less than 0 and more then 60 give expected results, but
2. Failing checks and not behaving as expected for the checks below:
   a. Integer
   b. Numeric
   c. Negative
   d. Not Float

```
  $seatsSTA = $_POST['seats']['STA'];
  $seatsSTP = $_POST['seats']['STP'];
  $seatsSTC = $_POST['seats']['STC'];
  $seatsFCA = $_POST['seats']['FCA'];
  $seatsFCP = $_POST['seats']['FCP'];
  $seatsFCC = $_POST['seats']['FCC'];
  $minSeats = 1; $maxSeats = 60;
  $totalSeats= ((int)$seatsSTA + (int)$seatsSTP + (int)$seatsSTC + (int)$seatsSTP + (int)$seatsFCA + (int)$seatsFCP + (int)$seatsFCC );

  if ( $totalSeats < $minSeats ) {
    $errorsBook['user']['seats'] = "Atleast one session must be selected. "; 
    // header("Location: index.php"); 
  }  elseif ( $totalSeats > $maxSeats ) {
      $errorsBook['user']['seats'] = "Too many seats selected. "; 
      // header("Location: index.php"); 
  } elseif ( !is_int($seatsSTA || $seatsSTP || $seatsSTC || $seatsFCA || $seatsFCP || $seatsFCC) ){
    // $errorsBook['user']['seats'] = "Please correct seat selection. ";
    header("Location: index.php"); 
  }
    elseif ( !is_numeric($seatsSTA || $seatsSTP || $seatsSTC || $seatsFCA || $seatsFCP || $seatsFCC) ){
      // $errorsBook['user']['seats'] = "NOT numeric character. ";
      header("Location: index.php"); 
    }
    elseif (($seatsSTA || $seatsSTP || $seatsSTC || $seatsFCA || $seatsFCP || $seatsFCC) < 0 ){
      // $errorsBook['user']['seats'] = "Negative number not allowed. ";
      header("Location: index.php"); 
    } 
    elseif ( is_float($seatsSTA || $seatsSTP || $seatsSTC || $seatsFCA || $seatsFCP || $seatsFCC) ){
      // $errorsBook['user']['seats'] = "Please correct seat selection. ";
      header("Location: index.php"); 

  }

  return $errorsBook;
}
```

Comment: The pattern / code style used in `is_int`, `is_numeric`,  `is_float` or in comparison related to `0` is wrong. eg `if(!is_int($seatsSTA || $seatsSTP || $seatsSTC || $seatsFCA || $seatsFCP || $seatsFCC))` should be `if(!is_int($seatsSTA) || !is_int($seatsSTP) || !is_int($seatsSTC) || !is_int($seatsFCA) || !is_int($seatsFCP) || !is_int($seatsFCC))`

Comment: Changed to:  if ( $totalSeats < $minSeats ) {
    header("Location: index.php"); 
  }  elseif ( $totalSeats > $maxSeats ) {
      // $errorsBook['user']['seats'] = "Too many seats selected. "; 
      header("Location: index.php"); 
  } elseif ( !is_int($seatsSTA) || !is_int($seatsSTP) || !is_int($seatsSTC) || !is_int($seatsFCA) || !is_int($seatsFCP) || !is_int($seatsFCC) ){
    header("Location: index.php"); 
  }- but failing